# Split multiple columns into rows by a delimiter

Tags: vba, excel, split, multiple-columns

I have two columns which have delimiters. Both columns will have the same number of delimiters. e.g `a;b;c` in column A and `d;e;f` in column B. In some columns there might not be any which is fine.

I want to be able split these columns into the exact number of rows and copy data from other columns as well. Therefore, the example above would have a total of 3 rows and result as below:

```
Col A   Col B
a         d
b         e
c         f
```

I have found the code below which i modified and works for a specified column but I want to apply this to multiple columns if possible.

```
Option Explicit
Sub splitcells()

  Dim InxSplit As Long

  Dim SplitCell() As String

  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    RowCrnt = 1

    Do While True


      If .Cells(RowCrnt, "L").Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If

      SplitCell = Split(.Cells(RowCrnt, "L").Value, "*")

      If UBound(SplitCell) > 0 Then

        .Cells(RowCrnt, "L").Value = SplitCell(0)


        For InxSplit = 1 To UBound(SplitCell)
          RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

          .Rows(RowCrnt).EntireRow.Insert

          .Cells(RowCrnt, "L").Value = SplitCell(InxSplit)

          .Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "A").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "B").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "C").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "C").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "D").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "D").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "E").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "E").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "F").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "F").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "G").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "G").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "H").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "H").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "I").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "I").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "J").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "J").Value
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "K").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "K").Value

        Next
      End If

      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

    Loop

  End With

 End Sub
```

Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: updated as missed delimiters

Comment: @"Hetal Patel" please edit your post rather than commenting on it. Thank you

Comment: Sorry Rawrplus, i am new to posting here and couldn't see the edit button until after posting

Comment: In your code, you are splitting the data in column L, but your post mentions you need to split it in two columns and gives example of A and B.  What is the actual other column?

Answer (score 0):

*Hello, took me a while, but I actually found a pretty fascinating / useful little procedure in this, so i was playing around a bit.*

I've created a little procedure which, where you can specify from which column you want to take the data, and into which column you want to paste the data. With the following invocation:

The `parse_column` procedure is coded with the following way:

```
' parses all the values into an array
Private Sub parse_column(columnID As Integer, toColumn As Integer)


    Dim totalstring As String
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change to whatever sheet you are working with
    Dim startingrow As Integer

    startingrow = 2 'change to whatever row you want the procedure to start from _
                    (i skipped first row, because it acts as a header)

    With ws
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnID).End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    Dim columnrange As Range: Set columnrange = Range(Cells(startingrow, columnID), Cells(lastrow, columnID))
    For Each Rng In columnrange
        totalstring = totalstring + Trim(Rng) ' we'll concatenate all the column values into a one string _
                                                (if you wish to take spaces into accoumt, don't use trim)
    Next Rng

    Dim buffer() As String
    ReDim buffer(Len(totalstring) - 1) '(avoid indexation by 0)

    For i = 1 To Len(totalstring)
        buffer(i - 1) = Mid(totalstring, i, 1) 'we fill in buffer with values
    Next i


    ' we paste values to specified column
    For i = (LBound(buffer)) To UBound(buffer)
        ws.Cells((i + startingrow), toColumn).Value2 = buffer(i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

So for example, if you wanted to parse all data from Column 1 (A) to Column 4 (D) you would invoke it in your procedure the following way

```
Private Sub splitcells()
    Call parse_column(1, 4)
End Sub
```

Beauty of this all is, you can simply loop this for all the columns you have in your sheet by a simple static for loop increment. So for example, if we had 3 columns:

Let's presume we have the following data:

[image]

*^ Note how Column C doesn't even have to be limited to 3 characters*

We could use a simple for loop to loop through all 3 columns and paste them to the 4th next column to the right.

```
Private Sub splitcells()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        Call parse_column(i, (i + 4))
    Next i

End Sub
```

Would produce the following result:

[image]

Comment: @HetalPatel is this still an issue or did my answer work for you?